# How to import or create a page template programmatically

Tags: templates, liferay

I want to create extensivy page template (not layout template) programmatically, something like Blog- or Content-Display-Page-Template.

How can I get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `LayoutPrototype` and set a `Layout` with defined portlets, thats all.

See Liferay source for creating a Blogs-, CMS-Template: `com.liferay.portal.events.AddDefaultLayoutPrototypesAction`